# AWS - Cannot ping/ssh my machine from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ping, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an AWS T2 instance. I created security groups to allow all traffic on all ports only from my local machine's IP. So when I try to ssh from my dev-machine with the pem file (`ssh -i pem_file ubuntu@ec2_public_ip`), it succeeds and I am able to log in.

However, after logging in to T2 instance, when I try to ping/ssh my dev-machine (`ping dev_public_ip` or `ssh prasanna@dev_public_ip`), it fails. I am able to ping websites (ping google.com). The outbound rules on AWS allow all traffic to all IPs on all ports.

I think there is problem on my dev machine end but I am not sure what that is and how to fix it. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: You're right: the problem is probably in your dev machine or your router. But without knowing the specifics people won't be able to help you. Except general advises like "Disable your firewall".

Comment: @SergeyKovalev I can give you any specifics you need. I am new to this. I don't even know what to give you ? Any help/questions would be great!

Comment: Some ISPs may block ICMP, which is the protocol ping uses. You may not be allowing ICMP out of your EC2 VPC. Your PC may not be listening for ICMP. There are so many things that it could be that we can't really help. You might be better finding someone local to sit with you.

Answer (score 0):

ICMP packets could be blocked, which would prevent ping responses.

I notice you said locally you use an SSH key, but on the dev server you don't. You probably need that SSH key to connect from your dev server, or at least have used ssh-copy-id to have copied your keys to the server.

You can also add -v to your SSH connection string to see more debug information about why the connection fails.